# Angular 8 - Bundle some npm package in lazy-loaded module instead of vendor

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

So I have a lazyloaded module called "ProductModule", which is responsible of my product page.

```
export const routes: Routes = [{
    matcher: productMatcher,
    loadChildren: './+product/product.module#ProductModule',
}]
```

In this module, we use a npm package for showing a gallery of picture (and a bunch of others). When analysing the build, I saw that all these packages was bundled into "vendor.js" chunk.

As long as they are only used and imported in `ProductModule`, do you know a way to bundle this lib in the same chunk as ProductModule ?

Thanks.

Comment: That is the disadvantage of using a vendor chunk. It might be better to not use it if lazy modules contain a lot of third-party dependencies. You can try what happens by setting "vendorChunk": false in angular.json?

Comment: Oh, this is a very good idea. Will try. Thanks.